# press button but not transfer between status in openerp ? please help me

Tags: python, eclipse, odoo

I try my best,when click button then from this status to diferrent status but nothing happen with click button , i really disappointment

```
<button name="" />
```

I see all my code and don't find mistake , everyone help me
    **code Python.py**

```
        _columns = {
                  'name': fields.char('Name', size=64, required=True),
                  'state': fields.selection ([('taomoi', 'Tao Moi'),
                                              ('choxemxet', 'Cho Xem Xet'),
                                              ('huy', 'Huy'),
                                              ('chopheduyet', 'Cho Phe Duyet'),
                                               ], 'status', readonly=False)



**workflow.xml** 

        <!-- Activity -->
        <record id="act_taomoi" model="workflow.activity">
            <field name="wkf_id" ref="wkl_tangluong" />
            <field name="flow_start">True</field>
            <field name="name">taomoi</field>
            <field name="kind">function</field>
            <field name="action">action_moitao()</field>
        </record>
        <record id="act_choxemxet" model="workflow.activity">
            <field name="wkf_id" ref="wkl_tangluong" />
            <field name="name">choxemxet</field>
            <field name="kind">function</field>
            <field name="action">action_choxemxet()</field>

        </record>
        <record id="act_huy" model="workflow.activity">
            <field name="wkf_id" ref="wkl_tangluong" />
            <field name="name">huy</field>
            <field name="flowstop">True</field>
            <field name="kind">stopall</field>
            <field name="action">action_huy()</field>
        </record>
        <record id="act_chopheduyet" model="workflow.activity">
            <field name="wkf_id" ref="wkl_tangluong" />
            <field name="name">chopheduyet</field>
            <field name="kind">function</field>
            <field name="action">action_chopheduyet()</field>
        </record>
        <!-- Transition -->
        <record model="workflow.transition" id="t1">
            <field name="act_from" ref="act_taomoi" />
            <field name="act_to" ref="act_choxemxet" />
            <field name="signal">salary_dexuatduoctao</field>
        </record>

        <record id="t2" model="workflow.transition">
            <field name="act_from" ref="act_choxemxet" />
            <field name="act_to" ref="act_huy" />
            <field name="signal">salary_huydexuat</field>
        </record>
        <record id="t3" model="workflow.transition">
            <field name="act_from" ref="act_choxemxet" />
            <field name="act_to" ref="act_chopheduyet" />
            <field name="signal">salary_dexuat</field>
        </record>
    </data>
</openerp>


**view.xml**


                            <button name="salary_dexuatduoctao" string="cho xem xet"
                                states="taomoi" />
                            <button name="salary_huydexuat" string="huy" states="choxemxet" />
                            <button name="tangluong_dexuat" string="chopheduyet"
```

this is my code for tranfer status in openerp but click button then nothing happens. 
Here include 3 file :python.py,view.xml and workflow.xml

Answer (score 0):

Your buttons are missing attribute `object`. For more details check the workflow of `sale` module.